# Warning message: In log(z) : NaNs produced when computing fevd GEV in R

Tags: r, warnings

I am trying to calculate return values for minimal temperature, which is negative and I got a warning message:

> In log(z): NaNs produced

It is very strange, because I got warning messages only for some vectors (21 of 95). I tried to restart R and do not know what else to do. Use `is.nan`? But I do not know where to incorporate it...

My data is:

```
mmm <- c(-18.78, -16.81, -15.92, -14.03, -12.58, -25.26 ,-22.57, -27.86, -15.39, -13.32,  -8.37, -15.10, -14.33, -14.50, -21.93, -17.75, -24.64, -24.96, -17.91, -17.68, -15.43, -18.16, -19.35, -27.34, -18.60, -14.34, -24.10, -13.75, -12.18, -17.02, -21.08, -21.14, -23.85, -17.80, -18.22, -11.15, -16.44, -15.20, -17.51, -12.33, -4.10)
```

Code:

```
library(extRemes)
library(xts)
mle <- fevd(mmm, method = "MLE", type = "GEV")
rl <- return.level(mle, conf=0.05, return.period=c(10, 20, 50, 100))

rl
```

The result is:

```
fevd(x = mmm, type = "GEV", method = "MLE")
get(paste("return.level.fevd.", newcl, sep = ""))(x = x, 
    return.period = return.period, conf = 0.05)

 GEV model fitted to  mmm  
Data are assumed to be  stationary 
[1] "Return Levels for period units in years"
 10-year level  20-year level  50-year level 
  1.998987e+67   3.880116e+88  1.393228e+116 
100-year level 
 6.205119e+136
```

Comment: Your sample code does not appear to generate the warning message you ask about.  [A 10 year return of 2x10^67 strikes me as, ummmm, impressive....]

Comment: The warning message appears after mle code and then, in my opinion, because of this warning I have the wrong result. A 10-year rl is very impressive. It should be between -10 and -30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my question, maybe it will help someone. Working with negative values (e.g. Tmin in C), the normal process in GEV analysis is to convert them by multiplying with * (-1), such that positive records are analyzed. Also, you can convert them to Kelvins. Once the GEV is fitted, you can easily back transform the result.